# Socket communication with Django

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to use Django for communication with some kind of server process? For example on my Django website I want to have form where I input connection details (host and port) and after connection I want to send some request or events to other server process (some simple action like slider moving or clicking a button). Can I use python socket programming for this or is there some easier way?

Comment: client side can be written in any language, it should implement/use http or socket at low level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use with django any python packages as with any "normal" python program. If you have a module, that communicate with your server, you can use this, if not, you have to write one on your own possibly with socket programming.